# To convert given minutes value from api into proper hours format and display on UI and post the same hours back in api minutes format

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is my json array format of API.

```
          'workingHours': [{
                    'startTime':'0060',
                    'endTime':0360  
                          }]
```

Data comes in minutes format, I need to display it in hours format for example : 0300 should be 5:00 am.

Here is my code-
I made  a timeconvert array to manually change sppecific minutes into hours.

```
$scope.minutestime=[{key:'0000',value:'12:00am'},{key:'0030',value:'12:30am'},                   
               {key:'0060',value:'1:00am'},{key:'0090',value:'1:30am'},                   
               {key:'0120',value:'2:00am'},{key:'0150',value:'2:30am'},                   
               {key:'0180',value:'3:00am'},{key:'0210',value:'3:30am'},                   
               {key:'0240',value:'4:00am'},{key:'0270',value:'4:30am'},                   
               {key:'0300',value:'5:00am'},{key:'0330',value:'5:30am'},                   
               {key:'0360',value:'6:00am'},{key:'0390',value:'6:30am'},                   
               {key:'0420',value:'7:00am'},{key:'0450',value:'7:30am'},
               {key:'0480',value:'8:00am'},{key:'0510',value:'8:30am'},
               {key:'0540',value:'9:00am'},{key:'0570',value:'9:30am'},   
               {key:'0600',value:'10:00am'},{key:'0630',value:'10:30am'},                   
               {key:'0660',value:'11:00am'},{key:'0690',value:'11:30am'},                   
               {key:'0720',value:'12:00pm'},{key:'0750',value:'12:30pm'},                   
               {key:'0780',value:'1:00pm'},{key:'0810',value:'1:30pm'},                   
               {key:'0840',value:'2:00pm'},{key:'0870',value:'2:30pm'},                   
               {key:'0900',value:'3:00pm'},{key:'0930',value:'3:30pm'},                   
               {key:'0960',value:'4:00pm'},{key:'0990',value:'4:30pm'},                  
               {key:'1020',value:'5:00pm'},{key:'1050',value:'5:30pm'},               
               {key:'1080',value:'6:00pm'},{key:'1110',value:'6:30pm'},                   
               {key:'1140',value:'7:00pm'},{key:'1170',value:'7:30pm'},                   
               {key:'1200',value:'8:00pm'},{key:'1230',value:'8:30pm'},                   
               {key:'1260',value:'9:00pm'},{key:'1290',value:'9:30pm'},                   
               {key:'1320',value:'10:00pm'},{key:'1350',value:'10:30pm'},             
               {key:'1350',value:'11:00pm'},{key:'1350',value:'11:30pm'}

            ]
HTML code:

<div ng-repeat="k in workingHours" >
  <p ng-hide="clinictime">{{k.startTime}}</p>

  <p ng-show="clinictime" >
  <select  class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="k.startTime" ng-options="time.key as time.value for time in minutestime" ></select>
  </p>  
</div>
```

I am selecting value properly but getting keys displayed. I want value to be displayed as well and send only key to api.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change to display the value:

```
<div>
    <p>{{k.startTime.value}}</p>

    <p>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="k.startTime" ng-options="time.value for time in minutestime"></select>
    </p>  
</div>
```

You could could access the key by: `{{k.key}}`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5824/

Comment: Thanks alot :)  But my ng-model is to show data from different source i.e from "workingHours': [{
                    'startTime':'0060',
                    'endTime':0360  
                          }]     .I cant changed ng-model="k" . I am getting GET from API which I show using {{k.startTime}}

Comment: I fixed it, just leave the `k.startTime` then and use `k.startTime.value`